# Texture won't show up

Tags: texturing

I have two meshes and one has a texture on it. For the second mesh with the leaves, I followed the same instructions I did for putting the flower texture on, yet the texture doesn't show up. The leaves are supposed to show green. I checked texture mode and it doesn't seem to be registering my texture because the leaves are purple. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save your file and share it? https://blend-exchange.com/ (or workupload)

Comment: @moonboots I packaged the files but I'm not sure where to find them. I'm quite new to blender so I haven't figured out everything yet
Nvm I figured it out

Comment: you need to share the link

Comment: @moonboots Ok got it uploaded
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sDXG1S5N" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sDXG1S5N/)

Comment: No material has been assigned to the leaves, you've only created a new slot, you need to create a new material in the Shader Editor, enable the Node Wrangler addon, select the Principled BSDF, press Shift T, in the Image Texture node select the image called PlumeriaLeaf

Comment: @moonboots I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: maybe share your new file, I've tried and it works

Comment: @moonboots here [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vn0o7aoD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vn0o7aoD/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a second material slot and you have assigned this slot to your leaves, but you haven't assigned any material to this slot yet, so select this slot and click on *New*:

[image]

Enable the *Node Wrangler* addon, in the *Shader Editor*, select the *Principled BSDF*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, it will create a chain of nodes, in the *Image Texture* node, select your green image:

[image]

Comment: I did that but for some reason, Shift + T isn't creating the chain of nodes mentioned above

Comment: have you enabled the addon called Node Wrangler? If it still doesn't work, create this chain manually

Comment: My bad, it is Ctrl T  ;)

Comment: Ok so I managed to get that chain, but I had to do Ctrl + T instead of Shift + T

Comment: It's fine! It's working now