# Texture won't show up in parts of my mesh

Tags: texturing

Trying to make a hat with a flower on it, so I imported a flower that I made earlier, but for some reason, the leaves are showing as white. They're supposed to be green as shown on the UV map and texture. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, didn't my answer helped? If not, please pack your images and share your file

Comment: @moonboots here [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SA0aGyQz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/SA0aGyQz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a leaf with <kbd>L</kbd>, in the *Material* panel, you can see what material is assigned to it:

[image]

Check the material you've assigned to your leaves, it's just made of a white *Principled BSDF*, you need to plug an *Image Texture* as explained in my [previous answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294277/texture-wont-show-up) (or change the *Base Color* to green, or assign it the other material but I couldn't test it as you didn't pack your images):

[image]